# Symfony2 - Purpose of `anonymous.key` in security.yml

Tags: php, security, symfony

I was setting up a Symfony2 application earlier that included routes that are both anonymous and restricted by HTTP BasicAuth. A basic firewall configuration using default values looks something like:

```
firewalls:
    main:
        anonymous: ~
        http_basic: ~
```

I could not find information on the options for the `anonymous` property, except in documentation for Symfony2's SecurityBundle Configuration, which presents a [full default configuration](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/configuration/security.html#full-default-configuration).

The `anonymous` property appears to have only one property: `key`, as shown on line *206* of the default configuration:

```
some_firewall_listener:
    # ...
    anonymous:
        key: 4f954a0667e01
```

I dug into the core codebase and the accompanying unit tests a little, and it appears to be a constructor value for [`AnonymousToken`](http://api.symfony.com/2.0/Symfony/Component/Security/Core/Authentication/Token/AnonymousToken.html) and/or [`AnonymousAuthenticationListener`](http://api.symfony.com/2.0/Symfony/Component/Security/Http/Firewall/AnonymousAuthenticationListener.html) but I haven't learned much from that so far.

There's a `key` property under `remember_me` also but I assume this has a different purpose.

I cannot find any other information that describes what this particular `key` property is, and what its purpose is. `AnonymousToken::__construct()` requires `$key` and `$user` arguments, so I assume this option is simply a manual override for a value that Symfony2 otherwise creates itself.

Can someone advise? Thanks :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When authenticating an `AnonymousToken`, they key of the `AnonymousAuthenticationProvider` and the token are compared. When they don't match, authentication fails.

The same applies to the `RememberMeToken` and `RememberMeAuthenticationProvider`. When the key of the token and provider don't match, authentication fails.

The key is used to determine that the token currently authenticating was created by the application itself and not submitted by a malicious client. This mostly comes from the fact that Symfony Security is based on Spring Security (Java) and Java has RMI (Remote Method Invocation) support. From the [Spring docs](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/reference/anonymous.html#ftn.d0e4187):

> The use of the key property should not be regarded as providing any real security here. It is merely a book-keeping exercise. If you are sharing a ProviderManager which contains an AnonymousAuthenticationProvider in a scenario where it is possible for an authenticating client to construct the Authentication object (such as with RMI invocations), then a malicious client could submit an AnonymousAuthenticationToken which it had created itself (with chosen username and authority list). If the key is guessable or can be found out, then the token would be accepted by the anonymous provider. This isn't a problem with normal usage but if you are using RMI you would be best to use a customized ProviderManager which omits the anonymous provider rather than sharing the one you use for your HTTP authentication mechanisms.

Comment: Well, that certainly clears it up! I ended up confirming my assertion above by setting the key manually and `var_dump`ing `security.token_storage`. That answered the "what", your question comprehensively answers the "why" :) Since PHP doesn't do RMI, I assume it's mostly redundant - or is it possible to maliciously create a token?

Comment: @Darragh as far as I understand it, this also applies to ORB (which is possible in PHP).

Comment: Interesting. I'm not familiar with ORB - can you explain?